# replace special characters with a space

Tags: xslt, replace, special-characters, xslt-1.0, translate

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Country"/>
```

If the `$country` contains apostrophe, then I get a problem.

For **XSLT 1.0**, what would be the correct way to replace every `'` with a space?
None of this works:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($Country, ''',' ')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($Country, '''',' ')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($Country, '&quot;',' ')"/>
<xsl:value-of select='translate($Country, "'"," ")'/>
```

What's the correct way?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show the definition of the variable `$country`. Does it retrieve a value from an input XML? If so, show the latter as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an apostrophe, you need to be using `&apos;` and not `&quot;`

Try this....

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate($Country, "&apos;", " ")'/>
```

If you did want to replace a quotation mark, and not an apostrophe, then you would do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($Country, '&quot;', ' ')"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the third argument be `" "` respectively `' '` to replace the apostrophe or quote with a space? Your suggestions would remove those characters.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Some bad copy-and-pasting on my part. I have corrected this to be a space now. Thanks!

Comment: I've mention it but I decided I will add spaces into it on my own :) Martin Honnen: Thank you for pointing that, Tim C: Thank you for your answer and adding spaces.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to declare a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($Country, $apos, ' ')"/>
```